# how to extract meta data of an URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meta-tags

I want to extract the image and description that is related to an URL. for example if the URL is https://www.google.com then I want to extract the google logo image  URL from it. I am working in NodeJS . Is there any npm library or API to to that?

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What exactly you're want to get? Meta-tags from the page? What is your environment? Is it nodejs or a browser?

Comment: yes the meta tags from the page  in nodeJS

Answer (score 5):

I'm using https://jsonlink.io endpoint, just make a fetch() call to their endpoint with the URL and get back the metadata

Comment: A great find! Deserves more attention.

Answer (score 3):

Use the npm package called [metascraper](https://metascraper.js.org/).

To get a logo from `google.com`, for example, you can:

```js
const metascraper = require('metascraper')([
  require('metascraper-image')(),
])

const got = require('got')

const targetUrl = 'https://google.com'

;(async () => {
  const { body: html, url } = await got(targetUrl)
  const metadata = await metascraper({ html, url })
  console.log(metadata)
})()
```

You'll get this as response for the above code:

```js
{
  image: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png'
}
```

Don't forget to add to you `package.json`:

```
npm install metascraper metascraper-image --save
```

You can add additional [rule bundles](https://metascraper.js.org/#/?id=rules-bundles) depending what you want to extract from the url.

Answer (score -5):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but maybe You are aiming for extracting url params from url?

check this out:

```
const url = "https://example.com/?product=shirt&color=blue&newuser&size=m"

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);

urlParams.get('color')
```

Will return "blue"

https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

**cause if u want to retrieve actual pictures and so on, u need an actual document behind url, not just an url.**